# How to use pattern mask for JSP input?

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, jsp, dojo

I'm using Spring MVC and dojo in my project.

We need to have an input for phone number by given format like: (###) ###-####

The phone number should automatically format as it's being typed.

The validation should be inside the text field it self with placeholder per each digit separated by '-'.

I tried to look over the web for an exist solution but I couldn't find any.

Comment: could post , how you manage to create you form ? with dojo or simple htmpl jsp page

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this library for phone number format?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/libphonenumber-js